# Vue state variable not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this code but when the selectCategory method gets called i don’t see product.categories being updated in the vue dev console.

```
  <li class="border hover:bg-blue-100" v-bind:class=""
                    v-on:click="selectCategory($event, category.id)"
                    >
                    {{category.name}}
  </li>

 export default {
  data () {
    return {
      product: {
        categories: []
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectCategory(event, id){
      this.product.categories.push(id);
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are calling the method

Comment: Btw, Normally I define vuejs methods like this  "" methodName: function(){ ... } .  ""Don't know what is exact differance between both. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Handling-User-Input

Comment: How are you getting `category.id`?

Comment: "category" is undefined. Please provide the relevant code

Comment: If you don't reference `product.categories` somewhere in the DOM the devtools will not automatically reflect the latest value either (i.e. the value is probably updated, just not showing in the devtools). Try using the refresh button or log the value in your `selectCategory` method and see if it shows the correct value.

Comment: What TommyF said is also true of certain events in Vue, such as "updated".

Comment: Just try to use `this.$forceupdate()` to update the DOM, after the pushing the id into the array (after `this.product.categories.push(id);`)

Answer (score 0):

```
     This might help you as referance.  

        <template>
         <div>
           <li v-for="category in Available.categories" 
               class="border hover:bg-blue-100" 
               v-bind:class=""                          
               v-on:click="selectCategory($event, category.id)"
           >
              {{category.name}}
          </li>
          </div>
       </template>

       <script>

         export default{
          data () {
            return {
              Available: {
                categories: [{
                  "name":"Fruites",
                  "id":1,
                },
                {
                  "name":"Veges.",
                  "id":2,
                }]
              },
               product: {
                categories: []
              },

            }
          },
          methods: {
            selectCategory(event, id){
              this.product.categories.push(id);
              console.log(this.product.categories)
            },
          }
        }
        </script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-v2zss?fontsize=14